# How can I get client-side and server-side performance metrics in Java EE (Servlets) project

Tags: java, servlets, performance-testing, performance-measuring

There is a Java EE project. Its goal is getting client-side and server-side performance metrics (as much as possible) of some predeffined URL with some frequency and collect that data for visualisation and so on...
So I expect to recieve those metrics (it could be done with different methods/libraries, it's okey).

I suppose that I can get responce time by using org.apache.http. But is there some better way with probably some more information besides responce time of server-side peromance metric?
And is there some library or method of getting cliend-side metrics?